# Looking for a Java based forum engine easy to integrate with existing user tables

Tags: java, forum

I'm looking for a Java based forum engine which is easy to integrate with an existing website.

Currently I have tables for users (including columns for passwords and email etc) and would simply like to add a forum.

From http://java-source.net/open-source/forum-software I've found these:

- JForum
- JavaBB
- jGossip
- JsForum
- nemesis-forum
- mvnForum
- Yazd
- FreeForums
- Sk Forum
- JForumFusion

Top candidates currently, are JForum, Jive, mvnForum and Yazd.

My question is, does anyone have experience of any of these or some other forum engine, and especially, experience on integrating it with existing user tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference, [JForum](http://jforum.net/) really met all my requirements. Their single-sign on (SSO) framework works like a charm, and gives me the responsibility to decide which username/password pairs are valid. No special cookies needed either, just my good old session map.